# Modular arithmetic help?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I don't even know if this really falls into the category of modular arithmetic, but I wouldn't know what to call it since I don't have a formal math education.

Let’s say we know the resulting values of the following equations:

$$(x-a)\ \text{mod}(y-b)\equiv 4$$
 $$(y-b)\ \text{mod} (x-a) \equiv -12$$
$$x \times y  = 231$$
$$a \times  b = 403$$

Is there any property of the modulus operations that would let me solve for all of the variables (a,b,x,y)?

*Edited with results for equations as an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, your post is not readable.

Comment: There are no equal signs in your post. What equations?

Comment: Are we to assume $a,b,x,y$ are all integers?

Comment: Yes, all integers

Comment: Notice that $403=13\cdot31$, and $231=3\cdot7\cdot11$. This certainly somewhat restricts the possibilities for the four unknowns.

Comment: In this case, yes, you use factorization for the last two equations to give you some possible solutions. But I'm looking for an approach that would work if the variables were very large integers and where factorization would not be practical.

Comment: parity arguments may help a bit.

Comment: $x=-33,y=-7,a=-31,b=-13$